# ¿Cómo obtener el hermano próximo en XPATH?

Tags: html, xpath

Deseo tomar el hermano siguiente a una estructura pero no logro obtenerlo, tomando en cuenta que tengo lo siguiente:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row list-items">

    <!-- Elemento que toma actualmente -->
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="update-nag">
        <div class="update-split">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="update-text">
          Lorem ipsum
          <a href="#">Lorem</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Elemento que hermano siguiente -->
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="update-nag">
        <div class="update-split">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="update-text">
          Lorem ipsum
          <a href="#">Lorem</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="update-nag">
        <div class="update-split">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="update-text">
          Lorem ipsum
          <a href="#">Lorem</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Mi ruta XPATH que toma el primer elemento es:

```
//div[contains(@class, "list-items")]//div[@class="col-md-12"]
```

y me gustaría poder tomar el próximo nodo, con algo como:

```
//div[contains(@class, "list-items")]//div[@class="col-md-12"]//next-sibling
```

¿Se puede hacer tal cosa?, ¿Cómo lo hago?.

Comment: Se puede obtener el hermano siguiente, pero viendo tu ejemplo, mi interpretación es que dado que tu XPath contiene la clase "col-md-12" y hay un único elemento de esa clase, no hay tal hermano.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Intenta con el *[axis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256456%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)* `following-sibling`

Así:

```
//div[contains(@class, "list-items")]//div[@class="col-md-12"]/following-sibling::*[1]
```

Answer (score 3):

No se puede conseguir lo que deseas partiendo de la ruta que utilizas en la pregunta, pues el resultado de dicha ruta contiene solamente elementos de la clase `col-md-12` y el *hermano* que deseas traer no es parte de esa colección.

Mi sugerencia es partir de esta ruta:

```
//div[contains(@class, "list-items")]/div
```

Esta te devuelve todos los elementos `div` que son hijos directos de `list-items`, y utilizarla como un arreglo.

Así

```
//div[contains(@class, "list-items")]/div[1]
```

Te devuelve el primer elemento de dicho arreglo, que es el `<!-- Elemento que toma actualmente -->`

Y

```
//div[contains(@class, "list-items")]/div[2]
```

Sería el `<!-- Elemento que hermano siguiente -->`, que es el que deseas encontrar.